# Recursion in Java program repeating same answer and not changing the value of "k"

Tags: java, recursion

What I'm trying to do is run 60 trials of this program. Each time I want the value of K to go down 1, until K=0. Currently i have only been able to get the program to repeat the same answer 60 time.

```
   package heatloss;

/**
 *
 * @author eric
 */
public class HeatLoss {

    public static void heatloss(double x, double m, double a, double k) {
    double heatloss = x - m * (x - a);
    if (k == 0) {
    System.out.println("Done With Trials");
    }
        else {
    System.out.println(heatloss);
    heatloss(x,m,a,k-1);
    }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double k = 60;
        double old = 60+k;
        double m = 0.10;
        double air = 40;


    heatloss(old, m ,air, k-1 );
    }
}
```

Comment: couple of trouble spots i see with your code in general.... 1) both your method and a local variable are called "heatloss", while this might compile and even work, it is confusing to the reader of the code, so you should probably change the variable name. 2) there is no need to do this as a recursive function. a simple loop will do. 3) the values of x, m, and a never change. presumably you want them to change on each pass.

Comment: Ok so i changed the program so K affects "double old". I still get a repeating number.

Comment: because x, m, and a never change, the variable heatloss will be calculated identically each pass, so you will naturally have the same number each time (i.e. "what paislee said")

Comment: `k` must be used in the equation to calculate heat loss, to see a varying output

Comment: I see what your saying. Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `k` *is* decreasing, because your function runs 60 times, as you said. However:

```
heatloss = x - m * (x - a);
```

is a constant value, because it does not relate to`k` in any way, and thus

```
System.out.println(heatloss);
```

prints the same value every time.

Answer (score 4):

You probably found it yourself: `double heatloss = x - m * (x - a);` always is the same, independent of k.

Comment: I fixed that. X = 60 + k - now, so its dependent now.

Answer (score 1):

To compare a double with 0 with == is a bad idea. Take look at this page: http://firstclassthoughts.co.uk/java/traps/java_double_traps.html

Comment: Yes, it is almost a wonder that k does not end up being 0.00000001 and negative `k`s come up. Upvote for double -> int.

Comment: No it won't - `k` is not part of the formula for `heatloss`.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable heatloss is never changing, because x, m, and a are never changing.  This is why the same answer is being repeated each time.

Answer (score 0):

Your k does go down in value. That's why it terminates. You never change x, m, or a in the next recursive call so why would you expect the value of heatloss to change if it's only dependent on x, m, and, a to change?